# counting nested types in pairs and tuples

Tags: c++, c++14

I need to count types in nested pairs and tuples and have come up with this snippet. If I use gcc's `declval()`, however, the following error occurrs:

/usr/include/c++/5.3.0/type_traits:2204:7: error: static assertion failed: declval() must not be used!
       static_assert(__declval_protector<_Tp>::__stop,

```
struct swallow
{
  template <typename ...T>
  explicit swallow(T&& ...) noexcept
  {
  }
};

template <typename C>
constexpr inline decltype(auto) declval() noexcept
{
  return ::std::move(*static_cast<C*>(nullptr));
}

template <typename T>
constexpr inline auto count_types(T const&) noexcept
{
  return 1;
}

template <typename ...A>
constexpr inline auto count_types(::std::pair<A...> const&) noexcept
{
  int r{};

  swallow{(r += count_types(declval<A>()))...};

  return r;
}

template <typename ...A>
constexpr inline auto count_types(::std::tuple<A...> const&) noexcept
{
  int r{};

  swallow{(r += count_types(declval<A>()))...};

  return r;
}

int main()
{
  ::std::cout << count_types(declval<::std::tuple<int, int, ::std::pair<int, ::std::pair<int, int>>>>());
  return 0;
}
```

My question is why and why does my `declval` implementation work correctly, while gcc's doesn't? I'll try to solve the problem using meta template programming next.

EDIT: Here's a fix, that compiles with both `gcc` and `clang`:

```
struct swallow
{
  template <typename ...T>
  constexpr explicit swallow(T&& ...) noexcept
  {
  }
};

template <typename C>
constexpr inline decltype(auto) declval() noexcept
{
  return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<C>::type&&>(*static_cast<C*>(nullptr));
}

template <typename T>
constexpr inline auto count_types(T const&) noexcept
{
  return 1;
}

template <typename ...A>
constexpr inline auto count_types(::std::pair<A...> const&) noexcept
{
  int r{};

  swallow{(r += count_types(declval<A>()))...};

  return r;
}

template <typename ...A>
constexpr inline auto count_types(::std::tuple<A...> const&) noexcept
{
  int r{};

  swallow{(r += count_types(declval<A>()))...};

  return r;
}

int main()
{
  ::std::cout << ::std::integral_constant<int, count_types(declval<::std::tuple<int, int, ::std::pair<int, ::std::pair<int, int>>>>())>{};
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::declval` is intended exclusively for compile-time logic. It is defined as, from [declval]:

```
template <class T>
add_rvalue_reference_t<T> declval() noexcept; // as unevaluated operand
```

There is no body to that function. It's just there to give you a type. You cannot do runtime operations with it. That's not what it's for.

Your implementation of `declval` involves explicitly dereferencing a null pointer, at runtime. That's just a misunderstanding of what `declval` is for and how to use it.  Additionally, your implementation of `declval` doesn't support lvalue references (e.g. I can `std::declval<Foo&>()` gives me an lvalue reference, `your_declval<Foo&>()` is ill-formed since you're taking a pointer to a reference).

---

The way to write something like this would be based on types. You can still write a function that takes a `std::tuple<A...>` and returns the number of nested types - it's just that that cannot be a runtime operation, it should encode that result into a type. That is, we start with:

```
struct adl_tag {};

template <class T>
inline auto count_types_impl(adl_tag, T const&)
    -> std::integral_constant<int, 1>;

template <class T>
using count_types = decltype(count_types_impl(adl_tag{}, std::declval<T>()));
```

And then just add other overloads for `count_types_impl()` for the other types we wish to support. The `adl_tag` is there so we can find all the overloads we need. Using fold-expressions to make this answer shorter, we can then add:

```
template <class... A>
inline auto count_types_impl(adl_tag , std::tuple<A...> const&)
    -> std::integral_constant<int, (count_types<A>::value + ...)>;

template <class A, class B>
inline auto count_types_impl(adl_tag , std::pair<A,B> const&)
    -> std::integral_constant<int, (count_types<A>::value + count_types<B>::value)>;
```

So that:

```
std::cout << count_types<std::tuple<int, std::pair<int,int>>>::value; // prints 3
```

Note that at no point is anything evaluated. None of these functions even have a body!

Comment: I don't dereference at runtime. It's a constexpr function, I dereference at compile time.

Comment: @user1095108 `constexpr` doesn't **require** it to happen at compile time, and you're never using those functions in a context that would add that requirement.

Comment: @user1095108 You're not using it as a template parameter... anywhere.

Comment: Ok, but, it is not necessarily done at runtime either.

Comment: I'm not convinced your code works, what's `+ ...` for?

Comment: @user1095108 [It works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac8033da1c835850). It's called a [fold expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), new for C++17. Clang supports them, but gcc doesn't yet.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Still I tagged my question with c++14 and c++ and c++14 is the current c++ standard.

Comment: @user1095108 The point of my answer was to illustrate the right way to use `decltype` with functions to solve this problem. The fold expression makes it shorter/clearer to write, and the C++14 way of doing a variadic template sum isn't particularly interesting for the scope of this question.

Comment: @user1095108 Please don't update questions with new questions. If you have a new question, ask a new question. I rolled back your edit.

Comment: Barry, please take a look at my fix. I think I've forced evaluation at compile-time.

Answer (score 3):

`std::declval` is not supposed to return an actual value, and it seems libstdc++ guards against it further to give you a more helpful message than a linker error would provide.

> Note that because no definition exists for declval, it can only be used in unevaluated contexts; it is an error to evaluate an expression that contains this function. Formally, the program is ill-formed if this function is odr-used.
>   -- [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)

Also, this: `return ::std::move(*static_cast<C*>(nullptr));` seems hardly safe, dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behavior...

Comment: I dereference at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: Currently, your `count_types` is not eligible for compile-time evaluation, since `swallow`'s constructor is not marked `constexpr`. If you fix that, the compiler [would have warned you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1da00701f5ac889) about the undefined behavior.

Comment: Nice catch, but it does say, that the behavior may be undefined, not that it is. The warning is unrelated to the dereferencing.

Comment: True, *that* warning is. If you test your declval [in isolation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fbfb29e9cd69c27), though, it's an outright error. Maybe UB detection in `constexpr` is still flaky?